# Extremely slow transaction commit on multi-node Hazelcast cluster

Tags: transactions, hazelcast, distributed-transactions

We are experiencing an extremely slow commit to hazelcast randomly with 2 node hazelcast server. We have XA transaction manager with database and hazelcast participating in same transaction and noticed that the hazelcast commit randomly but often take 5 sec. It happens more often on heavy load but also on low load could happen.

We can not reproduce the problem with one node hazelcast server.

Looks like copy the transaction log between hazelcast nodes when TWO_PHASE commit is required can take a lot of time ... but 5 seconds seem really an eternity to do this.

We are using Hazelcast 4.2.2

our hazelcast server settings are :

```
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.event.thread.count", "48");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.query.predicate.parallel.evaluation", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.operation.responsequeue.idlestrategy", "backoff");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.aggregation.accumulation.parallel.evaluation", "false");

        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.operation.thread.count", "48");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.operation.call.timeout.millis", "30000");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.enabled", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.stacktrace.logging.enabled", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.log.purge.interval.seconds", "60000");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.log.retention.seconds", "60000");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.threshold.millis", "100");

        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.clientengine.thread.count", "48");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.clientengine.query.thread.count", "48");
     

        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.enabled", String.valueOf(performanceLogEnabled));
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.metric.level", "info");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.invocation.sample.period.seconds", "30");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.pending.invocations.period.seconds", "30");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.slowoperations.period.seconds", "30");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.overloaded.connections.period.seconds", "30");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.max.rolled.file.size.mb", "100");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.max.rolled.file.count", "3");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.storeLatency.period.seconds", "60");
        properties.setProperty("hazelcast.diagnostics.directory", "./logs/diagnostics");
```

Answer (score 1):

My hypothesis is that it's because of replication from one node to another as on a single-node setup, you don't notice this issue.

To confirm, you might want to check your backup configuration, especially [this section](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map#creating-sync-backups). Set the backup count to 0: if it fixes the problem, then the next step will be to make the [backup async](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map#creating-async-backups).

Note that in that case, you'll be having consistency issues depending on which node you're on. Welcome to distributed systems...

Comment: yes but we can not afford backup 0 ... also backup async does not give the guarantee consistency or am I wrong? we manage to speed up the commit time with removing the settings en leave mostly default but we are still in research which setting causes the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem comes with distributed system: you have to put the cursor between full speed, unwarranted consistency and guaranteed consistency, best effort speed.